# PF10 Primefaces p:breadcrumb doesn't show separators among items

Tags: primefaces, themes, breadcrumbs

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- Java 22
- JSF 2.3
- Primefaces 10
- PF Themes Avalon, ui-lightness

I've migrated from PF8 to PF10 and p:breadcrumb doesn't show separators among menu items. Is there some incompatibility with PF10 and some themes?

[image]

**Basic breadcrumb**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <div class="card">
        <p:breadCrumb>
            <p:menuitem value="Electronics"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Computer"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Notebook"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Accessories"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Backpacks"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Item"/>
        </p:breadCrumb>
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using a theme that has been upgraded for PF 10? Breadcrumbs are rendered differently https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/6886

Answer (score 3):

You need a new Avalon theme from your PrimeStore account that is updated for PF10.0.0.

According to this page Avalon is complete and should be in your PrimeStore account for download: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Updates-Of-Premium-Templates-For-PrimeFaces-X

Comment: I can't say for sure but it is probably it. I got another error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67179778/primefaces-10-theme-avalon-3-0-0-classnotfoundexception-org-primefaces-avalon-co