# Primefaces 10 theme Avalon 3.0.0 ClassNotFoundException org.primefaces.avalon.component.AvalonMenuRenderer

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, themes

Environment:

- Jboss 7.2
- Java 11
- JSF 2.3
- Primefaces 10
- Primefaces theme Avalon 3.0.0

New versión of theme Avalon 3.0.0 seems that it miss class AvalonMenuRenderer on avalon-theme-3.0.0.jar.There is only META-INF folder

[image]

Could it be?

On loading the project migrated to avalon 3.0.0 I got this error.

**Error log**

```
14:56:14,600 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 83) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
  Source Document: vfs:/C:/desarrollo/workspace/accfor2/accfor/accfor-ear/target/accfor2/accfor-extra.war/WEB-INF/lib/avalon-3.0.0.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Unable to create a new instance of 'org.primefaces.avalon.component.AvalonMenuRenderer': javax.faces.FacesException: org.primefaces.avalon.component.AvalonMenuRenderer from [Module "deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-extra.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:382)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:291)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.addRenderers(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:323)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.RenderKitConfigProcessor.process(RenderKitConfigProcessor.java:180)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:271)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:121)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:127)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:118)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:403)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:138)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:155)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:246)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:443)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:237)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.15.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.2.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final-redhat-1//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: org.primefaces.avalon.component.AvalonMenuRenderer from [Module "deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-extra.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:431)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.createInstance(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:304)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.primefaces.avalon.component.AvalonMenuRenderer from [Module "deployment.accfor2.ear.accfor-extra.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.util.Util.loadClass(Util.java:333)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.5.SP2-redhat-00001//com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.loadClass(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:423)
    ... 43 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that issue is fixed and a new JAR is available.

See: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=68&t=66604